# Homogeneous polynomial in 4 variable with non degenerate zero

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials, real-algebraic-geometry, zeroes

I've got a very simple question about a homogenous polynomial, for which I cannot see neatly how to proceed (probably due to my limitations in algebraic geometry though). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

So, let $p:\mathbb R^4\to \mathbb R$ be a homogeneous polynomial of degree 4, and assume that $p$ has a non-trivial zero in $\mathbb R^4$. Is it true then that there exists $x_0\in \mathbb R^4$ such that $p(x_0)=0$ but $\nabla_{x_0}p$ is not the zero vector?

Thank you very much for all your replies.

**Edit:** Ok I need one more hypothesis that I missed: the polynomial $p$ takes both signs, otherwise any square would be a trivial counterexample, as pointed out in the comments.

Comment: What if your polynomial is a square?

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov I've edited according to your comment, thank you! I missed one hypothesis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed true. One can drop the assumption on $p$ to be homogeneous and dimension $4$ is not relevant, though the condition $\deg(p)=4$ is crucial. The statement follows from the following facts.

**Fact 1.** Let $q(x)$ be a polynomial in one variable $x$ such that $\deg(q)=4$ and $q$ changes sign. Then there is a root $x_0$ of $q$ such that $q'(x_0)\ne 0$.

*Proof.* Let us take the root $y_0$ of $q$ at which $q$ changes sign. If $q'(y_0)\ne 0$ we are done. If not then $y_0$ is a root of multiplicity $3$. It follows that $q$ has a different root of multiplicity $1$, and we are done. QED

**Fact 2.** Let $p$ be a polynomial of degree $d$ on $\mathbb R^n$.
Then any line $L$ in $\mathbb R^n$ can be slightly perturbed so that the restriction of $P$ to it has degree $d$.

*Proof.* This follows from the fact that the subset of lines in $\mathbb R^n$ to which $p$ restricts as a polynomial of degree $<d$ belongs to a hypersurface. (if needed I can give more details). QED

Now, let us deduce the statement. By the assumptions we know that there exists two points $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $\mathbb R^4$ such that $p(x_1)>0>p(x_2)$. Let $L$ be the line through $x_1,\,x_2$. By Fact 2 we can perturb it a bit to a line $L'$ so that $p$ restricts to $L$ as a degree $4$ polynomial, which changes sing. Now apply Fact 1.

Comment: Dear @Dmitri, your answer convinces me. It is indeed true that here it is the condition on the degree that is crucial. However one can ask himself the same question in $\mathbb R^n$, with a homogeneous polynomial of degree $6$. What I see here is that the dimension $n$ matters, for $p(x,y)=x^3y^3$ changes evidently sign, but it does not satisfy the conclusion of my OP. This is why I asked for a polynomial in $\mathbb R^4$, but here I agree that it is not important. Thank you very much!

Comment: Dear @Dmitri, may I ask you one more question? Do you know any sufficient conditions for a homogeneous polynomial of degree $6$ to have at least a non-degenerate zero? My example $p(x)=x^3y^3$ shows that the change of sign is not sufficient. On the other hand your reasoning suggests that if there exists a line $\ell$ such that the restriction of $p$ to $\ell$ has at least $3$ distinct roots then such zero for $p$ exists. Do you know if there exists other relevant criteria? Thank you very much!

Comment: Dear Gil, I think that in case $p$ changes its sign, and $\deg(p)=6$ the only examples that don't have points $x_0$ with $p(x_0)=0$ and $\nabla p(x_0)\ne 0$ are those that are cubes of quadratic polynomials. I.e. $p=q^3$.

Comment: Dear @Dmitri, this theory is really fascinating to me, because for some reason I need to find non-degenerate zeros for homogeneous polynomial of even degree. It seems that there is something going on behind all the facts you tell me, that still I don't fully understand. Do you have any reference in mind? Gil

Comment: Dear Gil, I am using the following  tool for degree $6$: any polynomial p can be decomposed into the product of irreducible polynomials. Moreover, if you look at the set $p=0$ and see that $p$ is vanishing on some $n-1$ dimensional component $X$ of the hypersurface $p=0$ with multiplicity $d$ one can conclude that $p$ is a product of $d$ polynomials all of which vanish at $X$.  Over complex numbers this is very standard. Concerning a reference, maybe one can start here: https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Irreducible_polynomial   Though it will not really help so much

Comment: So, over complex numbers you know that if you have  a $n-1$-dimensional irreducible component of the set $p=0$, and $p=0$ has more than one irreducible component, then there is a polynomial $q$ of degree $<\deg(p)$ whose zero set is exactly $X$ (where $X$ is one of components). Also, in case $p$ is vanishing on $X$ with multiplicity $d$ then $p$ is divisible by $q^d$ where $\{q=0\}=X$.